# How to generate a phone number with eight digits and country code 00223 or +223 with java Faker Library?

Tags: java, regex, spring

I want to use the Faker java library to generate phone numbers with 00223 or +223 followed by eight digits.The current behavior is that the format of the generated phone number does not match the regexes (^(+223|00223)(\d){8}$)|(^\d{8}$) and would like generate for example 0022378953023 or +22378953023 or 78953023.

This the method I invoke to generate a random phone number:

```
    private final Faker faker = new Faker(Locale.FRANCE);
    private PhoneNumber randomPhoneNumber() {

        return new PhoneNumber("00223"+faker.phoneNumber().phoneNumber().substring(0, 8));
    }
```

The phone Number class is:

```
    public class PhoneNumber {

    @NotBlank
    private String phoneNumber;

    private static final Pattern VALIDATION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(^(\+223|00223)(\d){8}$)|(^\d{8}$)");

    public PhoneNumber(String phString) {
        Assert.hasText(phString, "PhoneNumber cannot be blank.");
        Assert.isTrue(VALIDATION_PATTERN.asPredicate().test(phString), "PhoneNumber does not have proper format.");
        this.phoneNumber = phString;
    }

    public String asString() {

        return phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "generate this or that". Do you randomly want to generate both formats? If not, pick one and fake only that. I'm not clear on what your problem actually is. Please isolate the code that isn't working and provide an [MCVE] and an explanation of what your code is doing wrong and what you'd like it to do.

Comment: I want to generate for example in this code a phone number following 0022378953023.

Comment: The problem (from a quick glance at the `Faker` source code) appears to be that it generates the phone numbers in the format `###-###-####` (or others), such that you are retrieving strings with the dashes included. If you are simply trying to generate the number without slashes, there's no need at all for the `Faker` library - you can simply use random number generation to generate a number between `0` and `99999999`, using `String#format` to ensure leading zeroes are included for your output.

Answer (score 1):

The regEx you can use to check the match is :
`^00223[0-9]{8}$|^\+223[0-9]{8}$|^[0-9]{8}$`

With this regEx, you have 3 alternatives matches :

- `^00223[0-9]{8}$`
- `^\+223[0-9]{8}$`
- `^[0-9]{8}$`

`^` is used to check that you had the next pattern (00223 or +223) at the beginning of the number
`\` is used to not interpret the next character (the `+`)
`[0-9]` is used to check any digit
`{8}` is used to check that there are exactly 8 times the previous pattern (`[0-9]`, so 8 digits)
`$` is used to check that you have no characters after the previous pattern (nothing after the 8th digit)
And `|` is used to have multiple alternatives

Answer (score 0):

```java
String phoneNumberExpected = faker.numerify("89#########");
```